# Criterion for finite expectation

Tags: probability, integration

The problem is

> > 1. Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable and $\lambda >1$, then
> >        $$EX<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \int_0^{\infty}\lambda^xP(X>\lambda^x)\,dx<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^nP(X>\lambda^n)<\infty$$
> > 2. Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable, $g$ be a nonnegative, strictly increasing and differentiable function, then
> >        $$E\,g(X)<\infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g'(n)P(X>n)<\infty$$

Thanks for hints from Davide Giraudo and Kavi Rama Murthy, I have solved the first problem, but I am still struggled for the second problem, what I know is 
$$E\,g(X)=g(0)+\int_0^{\infty} g'(x)P(X>x)\,dx$$
but how to continue? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the first equivalence and the inequalities 
$$
\lambda ^n\Pr(X>\lambda^{n+1})\leqslant \int_n^{n+1}\lambda^x\Pr(X>\lambda^x)dx\leqslant \lambda^{n+1}\Pr(X>\lambda^n).
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\lambda^{n} P(X>\lambda^{n+1}) \leq\int_n^{n+1} \lambda^{x}P(X>\lambda^{x})\, dx \leq \lambda^{n+1} P(X>\lambda^{n})$.  Add these and conclude.